# JavaScript autocomplete atom

Tags: javascript, atom

Как в "Атоме" настроить автокомплит для JS? Поставил плагин atom-ternjs, но что то нет никаких изменений.

Comment: autocomplete-plus установлен ?

Comment: @zb' да, установлен.

Comment: А packages > atom-ternjs > configure сделано ? (Первые строчки в секции описания install)

Comment: @zb' http://savepic.su/6974476.png

Comment: Читайте внимательно матчасть https://atom.io/packages/atom-ternjs https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus